# CSS is not working until I run debugger in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having an issue that I never heard about. I have a "< div >" that does not get it styles until I open console. Any suggestions what it could be ?

here is my source http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjbGJ/

[image: no style]

and here is the other one.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have 3 errors.  Could you look in the console and let us know what they are?

Comment: @PatrickAllen only 3 <imgs> that im not using anymore. Already commented their line in CSS but the error still.

Comment: try hard refreshing your browser, ctrl + F5

Comment: Hmm.. Have you tried running it without JS linked up in the HTML file?  Also, if you resize your browser without opening dev tools, does that fix it?

Comment: @PatrickAllen Yes, if I resize it fixes... what is it ? O.o

Comment: We will definitely need to see some code to try to figure it out. You might want to edit your post/title to better reflect your problem now that we have a better understanding of what it is.

Comment: @PatrickAllen Ok, i edited it. There is a codepen link with my source

Answer (score -1):

Aways use a Server to test your code. Some css or js files don't load when you access from a local file.

Try to use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html) or Python's [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)